# Annotate Promotional Email HTML Code Markup | Doesn't work as expected

Tags: gmail, gmail-promo-tab

I followed the Google promotion email code template and drafted one demo.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview

and the code also passed Google makeup test
https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/

however, when I use my email tools inserting the following code into the HTML editor and send out the EDM, no effect appears, it just shows up like a normal email (no image/banner appears in promotion box).

I saw there is another document from Google but it only address the "one-click" / "go-to-action" email
https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/apps-script-tutorial

Would highly appreciate it if anyone can help to point out mistakes.

FYI Promotion email markup does not require whitelisting

```html
<!-- Paste your own code here, or change the existing code to experiment with what works -->
<!-- Feel free to paste the entire HTML of your email -->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "Organization",

// WARNING: Before sending email, either point the logo
// at your own image or delete the logo annotation.
//
// If showing a logo, we recommend using an https URL.
// It's not a requirement today, but may be in the future.
"logo": "https://www.gobear.com/hk//themes/custom/gobear/apple-touch-icon.png"
},{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "EmailMessage",

// Use this optional alternative subject line to avoid duplicate text
// between the subject, deal badge, and discount code.
"subjectLine": "【後疫情時代】幫你睥實全港理財貼士 "
},{
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "DiscountOffer",

// Describe your discount, this will be shown as a badge (eg "25% off" or "free shipping")
"description": "6月理財小貼士",

"availabilityStarts": "2020-07-18T22:51:01-07:00",
"availabilityEnds": "2020-07-31T22:51:01-07:00"
},{
// Promotion card with single image.
// We recommend using an https URL. It's not a requirement today, but may be in the future.
// Any image size will work and will just be cropped automatically.
// GIF & WEBP images are not supported and will be filtered out.
// Sample image is 538x138, 3.9 aspect ratio
"@context": "http://schema.org/",
"@type": "PromotionCard",
"image": "https://newtwb.s3.amazonaws.com/images/gobearhk/GoBear_Edm_banner_20200618.jpg"
}]
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: How are you sending the email?

Comment: Hi Rafa, we used a crm system called Netcoresmartech, inside we can use the html editor to paste our code at

Answer (score 0):

#### This appears to be a bug!

After doing some testing, it appears that neither the Promotional Email nor *any* Email markup seems to be working.

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Following the Apps Script Quickstart for Email Markup does not display the Go-To action](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162056628)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.